Formbuilder : individuals have relationship with themselves : bug or by design?
In formbuilder I have a very basic form, collecting first and last name of individuals.
It's set as "multiple", so that users can create up to two individuals (such as 2 parents / husband & spouse)


Then I want to create a "partner of" relationship between them.

Result :
A correct relationship is built between nom1 and nom2
BUT : nom1 is related with himself, which is probably logical from a computer coding point of view, but not from a "real life" / use case point of view.

I believe the relation between nom1 and himself (in red on screenshot) should not be created
What do you think ?

correct these should not be created to themselves - but your screenshot suggests that you are setting both Contact A and Contact B as Individual 1 which I don't understand.

i had a quick go at setting one up at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/asdf
using Individual 1 and Individual 2 and Relationship and when it Submits it creates Contact A and Contact B with a relationship between them - and does not create one between A and A

@petednz-fuzion  It works correctly with two separate individuals, but this is about the 'Repeat' feature. So 'Individual1' can represent multiple contacts.  See  https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/asdf2  That's when the relationship with itself arises.

It's kinda logical that it creates those self-relationships, but unlikely to be what is wanted.  I'd suggest creating a request on lab.civicrm.org

Thanks team. Yes, you correctly understood and reproduced the issue, which is logical but not what we should expect. I'll open an issue on  lab.civicrm.org

Ah right. yes hadn't tested what happens with 'multiple'. apologies
